# What does this Python one-liner mean?

Tags: python, syntax

```
s=p=1;exec"if s%p*s%~-~p:print`p`+','+`p+2`\ns*=p*p;p+=2\n"*999
```

[Source.](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Twin+primes/hiro.suzuki%E3%80%80/1187877291&py)

Comment: This is *not* syntactic "sugar".

Comment: obfuscated python !! who needs that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an unraveling of the basic idea.

```
# p = 1; s = p
s=p=1
#exec"if s%p*s%~-~p:print`p`+','+`p+2`\ns*=p*p;p+=2\n"*999
for i in range(999):
    # s%p = remainder of s/p
    # ~p = 1s complement of p
    if s%p*s%~-~p:
        # `p` = repr(p)
        print`p`+','+`p+2`
    # s = s*p*p
    s*=p*p
    # p = p+2
    p+=2
```

Comment: Could you clarify the part "s%~-X", where X is already explained?

Comment: Apparently, "~-~x" means `(1st comp (- (1st comp x))))` so is it just 1st complement then taking `-` and then again 1st complement?

Comment: @HH: the `~-X` basically does a `x-1`, but since that would require `(` and `)`, this is shorter ;) The `s%` part is simply a modulo

Comment: FWIW, `~-~p` is equal to `-p - 2` because of how 1's complement works, so the conditional works out to `(s mod p) * (s mod (-p - 2))`

Comment: I just see now that the actual function was `~-~X` instead of `~-X`. In that case it's pretty much the same except it's an inversion and the difference is 2.

Comment: Which is essentially (1's comp(2's comp(1's comp x))) `~1 == -2; --2 == 2; ~2 == -3`  just a shorter way to write `(x+2)`, 4 chars versus 5 chars.  Even though the result ends up negative the mod still serves its purpose.

Comment: `(...)` are needed due to the order of operations, `negation > complement > mod > (mult, div) > (subtraction, addition)` (off the top of my head)

Answer (score 7):

It calculates and prints the sets of twin prime numbers.

```
3,5
5,7
11,13
17,19
29,31
41,43
59,61
71,73
101,103
107,109
137,139
.....
```

Very cool :)

Answer (score 3):

The code is iterative.

1. `s=p=1`, initialization
2. `exec"f(...)"*999` is the same as `for i in range(999):f(...)":`
3. `s%p` is a modulo
4. `p*s` is a multiplication `(x,y)`, binary operation
5. `~-~` explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529452/what-does-this-python-one-liner-mean/4529488#4529488).
6. `\n` means line break,
7. `\ns` means a line break and `s` is a part of the declaration `s*=p*p;`
8. `p+=2` means the assignment `p=p+2`

Hopefully, other people can fill the gaps. For futher investigation, what is its recursive equation?